# Python3 - AppJar (tkinter wrapper) change function of a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, wrapper

So basicly I'm having a button and I want to change the function. The Button should have fnc HellWorld and if I click it fnc GoodbyeWorld.

My try:

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui()
app.setGeometry("300x300")


def HelloWorld(none):
    print("Hello World!")
    app.getButtonWidget("Button").config(command = GoodbyeWorld(none))

def GoodbyeWorld(none):
    print("Goodbye World!")
    app.getButtonWidget("Button").config(command = HelloWorld(none))

app.addButton("Button", HelloWorld, 1, 1)


app.go()
```

But if I do it like above my output is:

```
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
....
```

and then I'm getting a few error messages and that ends in a RecursionError.

Am I doing something wrong? (Probably, yes..)
Link to AppJar: http://appjar.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the appJar method of assigning functions and the tkinter method. You need to stick with one, and since I know tkinter, I'll suggest the tkinter method:

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui()
app.setGeometry("300x300")


def HelloWorld():
    print("Hello World!")
    app.getButtonWidget("Button").config(command = GoodbyeWorld)

def GoodbyeWorld():
    print("Goodbye World!")
    app.getButtonWidget("Button").config(command = HelloWorld)

app.addButton("Button", None, 1, 1)
app.getButtonWidget("Button").config(command = HelloWorld) # set initial command

app.go()
```

You may want to think about WHY you are reassigning the function; it seems very unusual. For your example, I would just use a single function that cycles through the data:

```
from appJar import gui
from itertools import cycle

to_print = cycle(["Hello World!", "Goodbye World!"])
app = gui()
app.setGeometry("300x300")

def output(btn):
    print(next(to_print))

app.addButton("Button", output, 1, 1)
app.go()
```

Comment: Without them I'm getting a TypeError: HelloWorld() takes 0 positional arugments but 1 was given

Comment: OK, I installed appjar just for you and edited my answer.